# I didn't understand this solution from Do Carmo's differential geometry book

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, differential-geometry

I'm studying the classical [Do Carmo's differential geometry book](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/docarmo.pdf) and I didn't understand the solution he gives to the item b of the following question:

[image]

**THE SOLUTION:**

[image]

**MY DOUBTS:**

I couldn't conclude $\alpha'(s_1)=-\bar t n'(s_1)$. I didn't understand either
why this follows that $\bar t=1/k$.

Answer (score 1):

The left hand side, $(\alpha(s_2)-\alpha(s_1))/(s_2-s_1)$ clearly tends to $\alpha'(s_1)$ when $s_2 \to s_1$.

For the right hand side we first look at why $t$ and $\tau$ have a common limit $\bar t$:
At the intersection of the two normal lines we have $\beta_1(t) = \beta_2(\tau)$ i.e. $\alpha(s_1) + t n(s_1) = \alpha(s_2) + \tau n(s_2)$. But since the curve is continuous, $\alpha(s_2) \to \alpha(s_1)$ as $s_2 \to s_1$, so also $\tau n(s_2) \to t n(s_1)$. Here $n(s_2) \to n(s_1)$ so we must also have $\tau \to t$.

Thus we have
$$\frac{t n(s_1) - \tau n(s_2)}{s_2 - s_1} \approx - \bar t \frac{n(s_2) - n(s_1)}{s_2 - s_1} \to - \bar t n'(s_1)$$

Now recall that $\beta(s) = \alpha(s) + \frac{1}{k(s)} n(s)$. But we also have $\beta(t) = \alpha(s_1) + t n(s_1)$. (Here we have different parametrizations, but that doesn't make a hugh difference.) Comparing these, and since $t \to \bar t$, we see that $\frac{1}{k(s)} = \bar t$.